# Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 14

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud_db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    function signin() 
    {
      $session_start;
      if (!empty($_POST['email'])) 
      {
        echo "not empty";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'employee' where email= '$_POST ['email']' AND password=   '$_POST ['pwd']'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if (!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
            echo "successfully login";
        } else {
            echo "login fail";
      }
    }

    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
      signin();
    }
?>
```

I am new in php, and i am trying to create a simple login page
here is my php code,a simple login php code.
when i try to run the code i get an error
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 14
i already defined the variable $con in first line ,then why i am getting this error.

Second - when i try to run the sinin function block i get an error
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 15
what does that mean, and how can i solve this.

Comment: Please supply the code

Comment: Please clean up your code, that's horrible!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it global inside the function or pass it in the parameter to access it

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud_db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function signin($con) 
{
  session_start();
  if (!empty($_POST['email'])) 
  {
    echo "not empty";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee where email= '$_POST ['email']' AND password=   '$_POST ['pwd']'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if (!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
        echo "successfully login";
    } else {
        echo "login fail";
  }
}

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  signin($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for finding the error, but you should suggest passing $con as parameter instead of global

Comment: -1: declaring it as a global variable inside the function may solve the problem but its a messy solution. A better approach is to passit as a parameter. Sometimes global variables are the right solution but in such a scenario one should not rely on an assumption that the variable is initialized in global scope - it should be explicitly declared as a global even if it is expected that the scope is global,

Comment: Thanks veerendra , it worked. can you please help me with this error mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 15

Comment: @AshuChauhan i am editing the answer and please accept the answer if it helped you :)

I think that error should be solved now as you are getting the connection now so query will be returning result

Comment: @AshuChauhan my answer will fix your second problem

Comment: @symcbean i have made changes according to your comment can i get my +1 back :)

Comment: @symcbean yeah, i don't like globals either but -1 was a bit harsh especially when he fixed the problem

Comment: @veerendra   if  i pass $con in the parameterit shows  Missing argument 1 for signin(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 28 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 8. with previous error  Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 15 and also the second error  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\login.php on line 16    remains same.

Comment: @AshuChauhan please try using the global variable approach only

Comment: @Veeranda - I see you've also amended the $session_start to sesion_start() but the query is still using single quotes around literals ('employee')

Comment: @AshuChauhan I have updated the query please use that query with the global variable approach

Answer (score 0):

not related to the question but:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM 'employee' where email= '$_POST ['email']' AND password=   '$_POST ['pwd']'";
```

will not work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'employee' where email= '{$_POST ['email']}' AND password=   '{$_POST['pwd']}'";
```

will work but it is still sql injection vulnerable.

read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Write the database side and the function side in diferent php script like this it may work

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud_db');
?>

function.php
<?php
include('database.php');
function signin() 
{
global $con;
  session_start();
  if (!empty($_POST['email'])) 
  {
    echo "not empty";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee where email= '$_POST ['email']' AND password=   '$_POST ['pwd']'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if (!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
        echo "successfully login";
    } else {
        echo "login fail";
  }
}

}


?>
```